# How do I present the home screen in my XCode app with code?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a game in which if a block of debris collides with the player, a boolean isHit is set to true. I have successfully made an if statement that says "if isHit is true, presentScene(gameover)". However, I have made a label and everything but I want to add a button that links to the home screen which isn't written in any code, since it is made in the layout. So, the question is: what code do I use to make it so if the button (which will be an image saying main menu) is hit, it returns it to the home screen which i made in the view controller layout?

Thank you so much for your time

Comment: You need to post more about your project. Generally you make a segue to connect an action to a view transition.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to navigate between view controllers using a button. Here's one programatic method.

```
// Write this when your want to navigate away using a button
button.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "goToHomeMenu"))

func goToHomeMenu() {
    self.presentViewController(HomeMenuViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

You can also use [storyboard segues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_DCTSTv1Mw).